# Creating arraylist using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, quantmod

I want to create an arraylist of the price data of certain stocks.

First, I selected my basket of stocks using:

```
tickers <- c("^GSPC","MSFT","INTC","NVDA","AAPL")
```

Next, I downloaded the price data using a for loop function:

```
for (i in 1:length(tickers)) {
  getSymbols(tickers[i],
             from = as.Date("2006-01-01"), to = as.Date("2009-12-31"))
}
```

Now, I want to add each stock data into an arraylist, so I tried something like this:

```
s <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tickers)) {
  getSymbols(tickers[i],
             from = as.Date("2006-01-01"), to = as.Date("2009-12-31")) %>%
             {. ->> s[[i]]}
}
```

But the output seems to only give me an arraylist of the name of the stocks:

> [[1]] [1] "GSPC"
>
> [[2]] [1] "MSFT"
>
> [[3]] [1] "INTC"
>
> [[4]] [1] "NVDA"
>
> [[5]] [1] "AAPL"

Is there something wrong with the code I gave after the pipe function?

Comment: That is because `getSymbols` returns only the name of the object. Try `get(.)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `lapply` to create your list object and make sure to set the option `auto.assign` to FALSE.

```
library(quantmod)

tickers <- c("^GSPC","MSFT","INTC","NVDA","AAPL")

# Get the ticker data
s <- lapply(tickers, getSymbols, from = as.Date("2006-01-01"), to = as.Date("2009-12-31"), auto.assign = FALSE)

# name the list objects
names(s) <- tickers

str(s)
List of 5
 $ ^GSPC:An ‘xts’ object on 2006-01-03/2009-12-30 containing:
  Data: num [1:1006, 1:6] 1248 1269 1273 1273 1285 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "GSPC.Open" "GSPC.High" "GSPC.Low" "GSPC.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
  ..$ src    : chr "yahoo"
  ..$ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2018-12-07 15:01:48"
 $ MSFT :An ‘xts’ object on 2006-01-03/2009-12-30 containing:
.....
```